# jQuery live() vs on()

Tags: jquery, element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.duplicate').live({
        click:function(){
            $(this).after('<input type="file" id="file" />')}})
})
```

I have this code using the `live()` function as it is deprecated,i have to use `.on()`,but it is not working for me.

This code is to create a new file element in the html page and when we click on the newly created file element dynamically created should be able create another  file element but with `.on` it is not working.
The functionality I wanna achieve is same like on the email page where we can create multiple  file buttons to upload.

Please Help

Comment: Please post the code you tried which doesn't work.

Comment: When your code doesn't work, post that code so people can help you sort out the problem and future readers with similar problems can see if there code has commonality with yours

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.duplicate', function(){
            $(this).after('<input type="file" id="file" />')
    })
})
```

More details at: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure 'on' will accept the same old format 'live' accepts.

Try the following instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.duplicate').on('click', function(){
      $(this).after('<input type="file" id="file" />')
    })
});
```

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Rubik answered about 33 seconds before me (we were probably writing the answer almost simultaneously). :) However, despite of the fact the answers appear identical, I've noticed his answer has a small error in the code (and extra ' } ' that will make it break).

Comment: you're right ;-) I've updated my answer. The other difference is the usage of the "on" function. Mine is based on "document" then look for selector ".duplicate".

Comment: Sure. :) Glad to help.

In regards to the usage of "selector" vs. "document", I based my answer in the question code. Notwithstanding, it also depends on the code requirements. Once I was building a tool that attached several events (click, drag, etc.) in several Elements from same "selector" (in that case, a class), and I found that being more specific (I mean, using the "selector" instead of "document") busted the performance quite a bit. ;)

In fact, if possible to use a container for that, even better. Cleaner code and even faster execution (less memory footprint).